# splitting dates in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

The time coloumn of my dataframe looks like the following

```
# time
# %Y-%m-%d
# 2000-01-01
# 2000-01-02
# ...
```

I would like to split the date coloumn in one for the year and one for the month (I dont need the days)
So the output should look like the following:

```
# year  month
# %Y    %m
# 2000  01
# 2000  02
# ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `lubridate` package, use the `year()` and `month()` functions to extract them, respectively, from a date object.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

DT <- as.data.table(yourDataFrame)

DT[, Date := ymd(time)]
DT[, year := year(Date)]
DT[, month := month(Date)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
# data:
time<-seq.Date(from = as.Date("2000/1/1"),to=as.Date("2000/5/1"),by="days")
df<-data.frame(ID=1:length(time), time= time)

# months
df$month<-month(df$time)
# or:
df$month.name<-months(df$time)


df
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try `separate`, e.g.,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% separate(d,c("year","month"),extra = "drop")
```

which gives

```
> df %>% separate(d,c("year","month"),extra = "drop")
  year month
1 2020    01
2 2020    02
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(d = c("2020-01-01","2020-02-01"))
```

Comment: Or use `extract`, and ini `separate`, there is an option to `extra = 'drop'` if you speciify only two columns

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot! Now I learn a bit more about `separate` (I didn't use `dplyr`) before :P